# how can i use the object_list in django listview in multiple templates?

Tags: django, listview, django-views

```
class PostListView(ListView):
model = Post
def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
```

I want to use the object_list in this listview in multiple templates. I have 4 templates each of a certain category in which i want to use this list and filter the list according to the template.So is it possible to use this list in more than 1 template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can over ride the get context data method in other views, and pass object_list as your context.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(YourSuperView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['object_list'] = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the method 
`get_template_names()`
and then in there you can choose the value of `template_name`

Example:

```
get_template_names():
    if X == 1:
        return 'template1.html'
    else:
        return 'template2.html'
```